# How to resolve "Error 409: too much contention on these datastore entities" in terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am new to Terraform. Here, I am trying to create multiple Firestore indexes in `GCP` using terraform. I get this error `Error: Error creating Index: googleapi: Error 409: too much contention on these datastore entities. please try again.` What do you mean by `too much contention!` Below is my Terraform script:

```
resource "google_firestore_index" "job_config2_index" {
  project = var.projectId

  collection = var.job_config_firestore

  fields {
    field_path = "customer_id"
    order      = "ASCENDING"
  }

  fields {
    field_path = "job_type"
    order      = "ASCENDING"
  }

  fields {
    field_path = "store_id"
    order      = "ASCENDING"
  }

  fields {
    field_path = "ms_asset_id"
    order      = "ASCENDING"
  }

  fields {
    field_path = "end_date_time"
    order      = "ASCENDING"
  }

  fields {
    field_path = "__name__"
    order      = "ASCENDING"
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "60m"
  }
}
```

Here are the logs:

```
Step #2: 
Step #2: Error: Error creating Index: googleapi: Error 409: too much contention on these datastore entities. please try again.
Step #2: 
Step #2:   on firestore.tf line 375, in resource "google_firestore_index" "job_config2_index":
Step #2:  375: resource "google_firestore_index" "job_config2_index" {
Step #2: 
Step #2: 
Finished Step #2
```

How do I resolve this ?

Comment: Did you tried to generate index by using Cloud console console as is mentioned in this [docuemnt](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/indexing#create_a_composite_index)?

Comment: No. I am trying to generate index using terraform.